# MYSQL: complicated query, multiple JOIN-s?

Tags: mysql

There is database structure (let's say legacy db) which can be changed and I need to implement an additional request to it.

**DB structure:**

```
Table "content" (few million rows)
=============================================
║ user_id ║ item_id ║ prop1 ║ prop2 ║ ... ║
=============================================

Table "descriptions" (less than 1 million rows)
========================
║ item_id ║ type ║ ... ║
========================

Table "properties" (multi million rows)
===================
║ prop_id ║ value ║
===================
```

I need to find all the items owned by a user (user_id) of some specific type (type) and calculate sum of multiplied prop1 and prop2.
I.e. ∑(prop1*prop2) where user_id=... and type=...
The final result is one integer value.

The problem is the data are splitted to 3 tables and I have no idea how to join them. May be it's not even possible to achieve it with a single query.

**Question:**
What is the best way to calculate the value with db performance point of view? Split to few simpler queries or run some complex one?

Comment: I don't believe there's a single query to handle this because your `prop` columns are not normalized (ideally the properties table would have an `item_id` column also, and then `content` wouldn't have any `prop` columns because that data is stored in the `properties` table. If your data were normalized, a simple `JOIN` would collect the data quite easily - something like: `SELECT
 EXP(SUM(LOG(COALESCE(p.value,1))) as product_of_properties
FROM
 content c
 JOIN descriptions d ON d.item_id = c.item_id
 JOIN properties p ON p.item_id = c.item_id
WHERE
 c.user_id = ?;`

Comment: (https://lists.mysql.com/mysql/166184 had a trick to simulate a `PRODUCT()` function similar to the `SUM()` function)

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Agree! It could be much easier to implement with 2 tables, but there are 3 and I have to find some effective solution...

Comment: Did you mean to write that the structure **can't** be changed?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it's very undesirable to change the structure because there are a lot of functionality built on top of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though your first table does not appear to be normalized, you should be able to join your TWO properties being considered.

```
select
      c.user_id,
      d.type,
      sum( p1.value * p2.value ) as SumOfP1TimesP2
   from
      content c
         JOIN descriptions d
            on c.item_id = d.item_id
         JOIN properties p1
            on c.prop1 = p1.prop_id
         JOIN properties p2
            on c.prop2 = p2.prop_id
   where
      c.user_id = parmSomeUserIDKey
   group by
      c.user_id,
      d.type
```

Notice the properties table is used TWICE... one for each alias reference corresponding to each individual prop1 and prop2 fields from the main content table.

If looking for a SINGLE Type, just add that to the where clause.

Additionally, if all you care about is the single number, and know both IDs (vs a description for the type), you could even simplify further via:

```
select
      sum( p1.value * p2.value ) as SumOfP1TimesP2
   from
      content c
         JOIN properties p1
            on c.prop1 = p1.prop_id
         JOIN properties p2
            on c.prop2 = p2.prop_id
   where
          c.user_id = parmSomeUserIDKey
      AND c.item_id = d.item_id
```

Note, as you commented about performance.  As long as you have good indexes, you SHOULD be good.  I would suggest the following exist.

Properties table, you probably already have on (prop_id)
but for Content table -- index on ( user_id, item_id )… explicitly BOTH fields in the index.  Since you want for a single user / item, it SHOULD be quite fast unless a single user / item has a few million rows (which I doubt).  Even if a person / item has 10k rows to compute should be very fast.

Comment: It's great! I will definitely try to apply your solution (the second query). What about its performance? Is not it too heavy for the amount of data I mentioned above (few million rows)?

Comment: @SergeyKrivenkov, see revised note at bottom about indexes

Comment: Thank you. The suggested solution works fine and its performance looks good!